# Управление типами оповещений, которые вы получаете благодаря нашей новой настройки электронной почты

Tags: обсуждение, обновление, почта

## Резюмируя:

Несколько дней назад мы запустили новую функцию настроек электронной почты, которая позволяет вам выбирать типы сообщений, которые вы не хотите получать от нас.

**[>> Изменить настройки электронной почты](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current)**

## Мы упростили включение и отключение отдельных типов электронной почты

В нашем предыдущем пользовательском интерфейсе описания категорий электронной почты были весьма запутанными, а иногда и избыточными. Кроме того, функции выбора и отказа были разбросаны в разных сообществах Stack Exchange, с разными способами настройки предпочтений для разных частей наших сайтов.

[image: Старые пользовательские интерфейсы электронной почты]

Новая функция «Параметры электронной почты» - это универсальный шлюз для управления всеми вашими подписками во всех сообществах Stack Exchange. Теперь достаточно указать в одном месте то, что вы не хотите получать от нас. Кроме того, если мы отправим вам электронное письмо, вы можете использовать вложенную в письмо ссылку для отмены подписки в один клик, чтобы автоматически оставить рассылку писем данного типа. Наши новые настройки электронной почты удобны для мобильных устройств и позволяют вам управлять настройками электронной почты "на ходу".

[image: Новый интерфейс настроек электронной почты]

## Приносим извинения, если вы недавно получили электронную почту, которую не хотели видеть.

Мы работаем в тени, чтобы запустить эти новые настройки электронной почты в течение последних нескольких месяцев. Хотя всё планирование происходило за кулисами, мы отправили несколько рекламных компаний по электронной почте.

Наш подход состоял в том, чтобы классифицировать рассматриваемую кампанию как составную часть нового списка адресов электронной почты, к которому она принадлежала бы, если бы настройки электронной почты уже были запущены в режиме реального времени:

- Если вы уже выбрали существующий список адресов электронной почты, который был переименован или объединен с другим списком, мы перевели ваш существующий вариант в новый список. У нас также было немного внутренних дебатов о том, какие типы электронных писем должны выходить из разных списков. Мы отправили несколько писем из списка «Советы и рекомендации», который с тех пор был реклассифицирован как принадлежащий к списку «Рекомендуемые вакансии». Мы понимаем, что это не идеальный пользовательский опыт, и некоторые из вас [подняли такие проблемы](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353732/why-did-i-get-a-job-email) (англ.) на Мете.
- Если вы недавно получили сообщение по электронной почте и отменили подписку на конкретный список адресов электронной почты, мы сохранили ваши настройки. Вы не были возвращены в список после того, кок мы переименовали или объединили его. Например, если вы отказались от списка «Советы и напоминания» после получения электронной почты «Оповещения о вакансиях», вы также отказались от списка «Рекомендованные вакансии».
- Если вы ранее не подписались на все списки, мы НЕ добавили вас в новые списки. В таком случае, вы все еще не будите подписаны на все существующие списки. Единственное электронное письмо, которое вы все еще можете получать, - это сообщения, которые вы явно указали, например, информационные бюллетени, подписки на вопросы или оповещения о работе. И, конечно же, мы можем иногда отправлять вам транзакционные письма и юридические уведомления, связанные с вашей учетной записью.

## Подпишитесь на наш новый список рассылки "Исследование"

В рамках запуска обновлённых настроек электронной почты мы создали новый список, который не существовал в нашем старом интерфейсе: Исследование.

Если вы хотите высказать свое мнение в нашем ежегодном опросе разработчиков, принять участие в тестах на удобство использования Stack Overflow или посетить опросы сторонних технологий, пожалуйста, подпишитесь на список исследований.

Вы НЕ были автоматически включены в этот список.

В следующей версии «Настроек электронной почты» некоторое количество пользователей, которое захотело получить заявки на исследования, будут добавлены в список исследователей. Это пользователи, которые проявили интерес через опрос разработчиков 2017 года, ответили на соответствующие объявления «Stack Overflow» или участвовали в прошлых исследовательских проектах.

В будущем вновь зарегистрированные пользователи Stack Overflow будут включены в этот список только в том случае, если они укажут, что хотят получать от нас рекламные письма.

**[>> Подписаться на список исследований](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current)**

## Подробнее о каждом типе письма

В нашем новом интерфейсе мы попытались быть максимально ясными и лаконичными по каждому типу электронного письма, но вот немного более полные комментарии по каждому из типов.

- **Обновления и нововведения:** включите, если хотите быть одним из первых, кто получит возможность получить исчерпывающую информацию на новый продукт или функцию, посмотреть результаты нашего ежегодного опроса разработчиков или узнать, что происходит на Stack Overflow.
- **Советы и напоминания:** электронные письма, описывающие вашу активность на сайте. Например, новые пользователи получают приветственную электронную почту, когда создают учетную запись на «Stack Overflow», а существующие пользователи получают случайные напоминания в случае, если им необходимо принять меры. Поскольку эти электронные письма являются транзакционными по своей природе, у всех пользователей они включены по умолчанию. Однако, если вы не хотите получать данные сообщения, то можете легко отказаться от рассылки.
- **Входящие сообщения:** еженедельные, ежедневные или 3-ёх часовые уведомления, которые формируются для вас на Stack Overflow и других сайтах Exchange. Они в основном связаны с вашими вопросами, комментариями и ответами.
- **Основные этапы сообщества:** письма, связанные с вашими конкурсными вопросами, репутацией и новыми пользователями. Поскольку эти электронные письма являются транзакционными по своей природе, у всех пользователей они включены по умолчанию. Однако, если вы не хотите получать данные сообщения, то можете легко отказаться от рассылки. Если у вас есть доступ к участию в акциях, мы уведомим вас об этом. Возможно поэтому вы можете захотеть, чтобы данный пункт был включен.
- **Исследование:** как описано выше, новая возможность, специально предназначенная для проведения опросов, тестирования на полезность и участия в других исследованиях.
- **Бюллетень:** еженедельные сборки главных вопросов из Stack Overflow и других сообществ Stack Exchange. Вы будите получать сообщений из тех сообществ, в которых включили данный пункт.
- **Подписка на вопросы:** оповещения по электронной почте при появлении новых вопросов на основе технических тегов или других установленных вами критериев. Вы получите их только в том случае, если вы специально настроили одну или несколько подписок на фильтры в Stack Overflow или на других сайтах Exchange.
- **Рекомендованные вакансии:** электронные письма, которые сообщают о свободных позициях и компаниях, нанимающих сотрудников на [stackoverflow.com/jobs](https://www.stackoverflow.com/jobs) (англ.)(не действует на stack overflow на русском). Данный тип бесценен, если вы активно ищете новую работу, и простой способ видеть доступные вакансии в случае, если будите открыты для новых возможностей. Мы пытаемся отправить вам только самые релевантные рекомендации, основанные на ваших [предпочтениях работы](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) (англ.), местоположении, технических тегах и других факторах. Если вы предпринимаете действия, указывающие на то, что вы сейчас находитесь в поисках работы, вы будете получать эти электронные письма чаще, чем пользователи, которые этого не делают.
- **Оповещения о вакансиях:** ежедневные или еженедельные сводки новых вакансий, которые соответствуют вашим критериям поиска. Вы получите их, только если вы явно подписались на оповещения о поиске работы.

## Выглядит отлично! Что теперь?

Новая функция настроек электронной почты сегодня доступна для всех пользователей. Целью здесь является упрощение понимания типов писем, которые мы отправляем, предоставляя пользователям полный контроль над настройкой оповещений. Поэтому вы можете быть уверены, что будите получать только те письма, которые вы действительно хотите видеть.

**[>> Изменить настройки электронной почты](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current)**

Мы считаем, что эта новая версия гораздо более интуитивно понятна, но если что-то все еще сбивает вас столку или не работает правильно, сообщите нам об этом.

- Поделитесь своими мнениями о данной системе в ответах здесь.
- Чтобы сообщить об ошибке, создайте отдельный вопрос, используя теги [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82) и [почта](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d1%82%d0%b0).

Comment: **tl;dr** О чем это?

Comment: @avp Редактируйте, если что не так. tl;dr - "too long; didn't read". У нас с этим словосочетанием не очень много аналогов.

Comment: Вы бы вкратце (в начале сообщения) написали, что это даст (для чего вообще применять (и стоит ли...))

Comment: Николай, перелогинься! // P.S. не хватает фразы "свободный перевод вопроса..."

Comment: @alexolut, работает и из отпуска, трудяга!